# logical operator and dates in AWK

Tags: awk

I just wanted to know if AWK program in unix let you compare dates with logical operators

E.g : will this expression 2021-11-12 <= 2021-11-13 will evaluate to        true? and if not, how can I compare dates more efficiently.

Comment: While the answer to the specific question you asked is "yes", that doesn't mean there isn't a way to compare dates far more efficiently depending on the context in which you use that information. If you ask a new question with a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input, expected output and code then we can help you with the bigger question of doing whatever it is you're trying to do efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

`"2021-11-12" <= "2021-11-13"` evaluates to true.

Example:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ if("2021-11-12" <= "2021-11-13"){ print "okay" } }'
```

Output:

```
okay
```

As completed by [tink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1394729/tink) this works because of your particular date format; it is naturally sortable in string comparisons. If you switch to `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD/MM/YYYY` it won't work.